# cmake auto search of libraries dependencies from folder

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker

I want to build an executable that requires a single library `/opt/foo/lib/liba.a`. but this library has its own dependency, which has its own dependency and so on:

```
my_exe <- /opt/foo/lib/liba.a <- /opt/foo/lib/libb.a <- /opt/foo/lib/libc.a <- ...
```

`left <- right` means "left depends on right"

I want to tell cmake to handle all `liba.a` dependencies by itself from `/opt/foo/lib/`.
this is my current CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_executable (my_exe ${my_sources})
target_include_directories(my_exe PUBLIC /opt/foo/include/foo.h)
target_link_libraries(my_exe /opt/foo/lib/liba.a)
install (TARGETS my_exe COMPONENT my_component DESTINATION bin)
```

currently I get a lot of undefined reference for symbols that are in `/opt/foo/lib/` but not defined in `liba.a` libraries becuase they are not linked.

Comment: "I want to tell cmake to handle all liba.a dependencies by itself" - You can *want* that all you like, but that doesn't mean you'll get it.

Comment: There is no question in your post. In the spirit of this forum, please ask a question. `I want to tell cmake to handle all liba.a dependencies by itself from /opt/foo/lib/` I do not understand. What if "cmake doesn't listen"? There is no such functionality.

Comment: Unless there's a find module/cmake configuration script available you're basically out of luck. Static library files don't contain info about where they expect to get the missing symbols from. For the same reason no linker will tell you the translation unit that's missing an implementation, if you get a undefined reference error; it just tells you which symbol is missing and which function is using the symbol. This issue exists whether you're using cmake or something else.